# I am unable to install xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, installation

I downloaded the Xamarin installer from the Microsoft website. I already have Visual Studio 2012 installed in my Windows 7 SP1. When I started the installer, I just clicked next. but after that nothing is happening. though I can see the process (XamarinInstaller.exe) running in the task manager but nothing is happening. What do I do?

Comment: Internet is enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to get around this would be to do a manual install of the required items.

If you reach out to contact@xamarin.com we can send you the links to the latest installers.